# Boot Sector Missing in External hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive, sectors

Yesterday I needed to copy some data from my girlfriend's laptop to mine. To do so I just copied my whole data from my external hard drive to my PC and used the hard drive for data exchange. After copying the data, I made a low-level format and copied my whole stuff back on my external hard drive.

But, now neither Ubuntu nor Windows can detect the hard drive and I can't format it again because I removed the data from my laptop. *Does it mean that the boot sector is corrupted?*

If so, what can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into a LiveCD. I recommend trying the [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) one. See if it can detect your system. If it can, try using a Linux LiveCD, and attempt to mount it, then salvage anything possible.

Comment: Gparded detects the drive but how can I access the data? I think I need to fix the boot sector or file system. How could I proceed? Thank you.

Comment: You could run an fsck from a LiveCD. Open it up, pop open a terminal, then locate your HD. So fsck /dev/sda#